# Invoking rabbitmq publisher from java code

Tags: java, eclipse, rabbitmq, apache-commons

I have 2 basic programs.first one is called `ext.java` and second one is called `send.java`.content to be published is located in a file called `data`

- The first java program opens the command prompt and executes a second java
  program.
- The second java program then publishes file content to queue in    rabbitmq
  server.

I use apache commons library function `FileUtils.readFileToString(file,format)` to read file.
When I execute `send.java qname filepath` from command line it pushes the contents.
But when I invoke the same from `ext.java` program , passing command line arguements ( which is in an eclipse project ),it throws an exception as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
```

The environment variables are all set properly.Here are the code files.

**ext.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Pradeep\\Desktop\\pros\\externalJava\\data");                 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java send f0 "+f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

**send.java**

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
import java.io.File;

public class send {

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
     ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel(); 
    File f = new File(argv[1]);
    String message = FileUtils.readFileToString(f,"UTF-8");
    channel.basicPublish("", argv[0], null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    channel.close();
    connection.close(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify `classpath` as well in order to point the JVM where to look for `FileUtils` (and `rabbitmq` related classes as well). Here you have related documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Another way would be to create executable `JAR` so the classpath would be included in JAR's manifest file resulting in no need to specify the classpath on CLI. It would be ran like `java -jar Executable.Jar`

So try this:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -cp PathToYourLibraries send f0 "+f.getAbsolutePath());
```

It works from `eclipse` because it sets correct classpath transparently to the user - adds all entries from `libraries` to the classpath as well as path to compiled classes.